# Testing Whether a Remote MessageQueue Exists (using C#)

Tags: c#, msmq

How can I tell whether a remote message queue [exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.exists.aspx%0A)?  The documentation states that the "Exists" method does not work for remote machines.

The following is not valid (I know the queue path is accurate since I am able to send messages to the queue):

```
if (!MessageQueue.Exists(@"FormatName:Direct=TCP:192.168.2.58\Private$\MyQueue"))
  throw new InvalidOperationException("Queue does not exist");
```

The problem is that sending a message to a network address that does not have a listening queue behind it does not cause an exception.  Having an exception thrown for an invalid queue address is critical to our application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an article about this:

> Frank's alternative approach is to make use of other features that
>   MSMQ provides, such as negative acknowledgements messages with
>   administration queues.
>
> What should happen is that either:
>
> - the message will be delivered successfully to the destination queue
> - a negative acknowledgement (NACK) will be returned to the
>     administration queue with a class of  "The destination queue does not
>     exist." (MQMSG_CLASS_NACK_BAD_DST_Q) Alternatively you could use
>     negative source journaling and, on failure to deliver, should see the
>     same class of NACK in the corresponding "Dead-letter messages" system
>     queue.
>
> In summary, don't check if the queue exists but instead handle the
>   non-delivery of the message should it turn out that the queue doesn't
>   exist.

http://blogs.msdn.com/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/07/31/checking-if-msmq-queues-exist-is-hard-work-so-should-you-bother.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What if the remote Q was controlled by a third party where you do not have any control?

You'd better have some kind of timeout checks instead of relying on remote info.